# How to say "influenza vaccine injection" in oral English?

Tags: american-english

Is there any word replace "influenza vaccine injection" in oral English?

Comment: Unless there's some incredibly obscure definition of "oral" that I'm not aware of, oral English and written English are identical, and so you would just say the phrase "influenza vaccine injection." Granted, that's a bit of a mouthful and personal preference would likely lead you to say something else, but "influenza vaccine injection" is perfectly valid "oral English."

Comment: Yes, the words look like very long, I guess people say something shorter than this one.

Comment: Well, most people would say "flu shot".

Comment: I think you're confusing "written" and "oral" with "formal" and "informal".

Comment: @HotLicks That's true, I'm looking for a better way to ask this kind of questions. I felt people didn't understand what I want to ask…you corrected me. I would say "informal" in next ask. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: And, of course, if it's oral then it's "flu spray".

Comment: In British English, most would say *'flu jab*. But *shot* would be understood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you clarify what you mean by oral English? I'm thinking what you're looking for would be "flu shot." But I am not 100% sure what you mean.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. I know written English is longer and harder to pronunciation. When I was in America, looks like people always speak English by different way, the words was shorter and easy to pronounce, but hard to find in dictionary.

Comment: Written English is not longer and harder to pronounce. It just depends on what you are reading. ;-) Pretty much anything said orally can be written, and anything written can be read aloud. Some languages (e.g. French) are a bit different, in practice, between written and spoken, but English is not one of them. Of course some written English is more formal than most spoken English, but most written English is not.

Comment: @Drew Thanks. But what about "flu shot"? It's same mean in dictionary, but shorter and easier to pronounce. And more locally looks like. Even in China, written Chinese is bit different with Oral English, people never speak like reading book. :-) I guess same in American. That's what I want to learn.

Comment: @Drew sorry, typo. "Written Chinese is bit different with Oral Chinese".

Comment: @Wilber82: The difference you cite (which does exist in English, of course) is a difference between two ways of speaking English (and there are an infinite number of ways, of course). It is not a difference between spoken and written English. *Influenza vaccination by injection* is perhaps more medical/scientific and more precise. *Flu shot* is perhaps more informal and less precise. They can both be, and are, spoken.